# blazor loading spinner when component is loading html/css

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have a small thing that I need to do. There's my problem. I open a component, and then I can click "edit" and then I need 3-4 seconds while that need html/css is shown on the page. What I'm trying to do is that when I click "edit" I set "loading = true", and when component finishes rendering that new html/css I set "loading = false". Here is a sample of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if (!edit) {
   <h2>test</h2>
   @foreach (var item in items) {
      <p>Test item</p>
   }
}
else {
   <button @onclick = "() => { edit = true; }">
   <h2>test other </h2>
   <input />
   <input />
}
```

This is how I set loading spinner to show on page:

```
await InvokeAsync(() => { loading = true; });
await InvokeAsync(() => { loading = false; });
```

So, my question is how can I make that when a person presses edit, the spinner automatically starts spinning on the screen. I know how to do it when OnInitializedAsync, but at this specific situation, it's not being initialized, it just shows a different part of the component (but it takes 5 seconds, huge code). Is there a way?

Comment: Are you calling ‘StateHasChanged()’ after setting your loading property/field?

Comment: nope, don't set it. "await InvokeAsync(() => { loading = true; });" automaticaly does the job. But that's not the problem. Problem is that I don't understand lifcycle of blazor components. So no idea where to put this "loading =true" and "loading = false". Is it in OnAfterRenderAsync? How do I put the logic for this to work

Comment: @PovilasDirse you normally place it before and after the call to load the data. Sometimes I have had to use `Thread.Sleep(1)` to yield for the screen to update after each time you set the loading flag.

Comment: so, I would have like this: @onclick = "() => { await logic(); }". Inside "logic" method I would sleep the thread and set edit to true?

Comment: @PovilasDirse yes before and after the data or whatever is taking the time. Inside "logic"  edit = true; ThreadSleep(1); StateHasChanged(); Do your slow code ....; edit = false;  StateHasChanged();

Comment: No, do not use Thread.Sleep().

Comment: Bit on the side, but take a look at already made packages for spinkits, f.eks. BlazorProd.Spinkit. Maybe you like it. BlazorPro has some good youtube videos is you like to customize. I wrapped it in a component with customizations, so all I do is: <my_spinner isLoading="loading"></my_spinner>, where loading is a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need StateHasChanged for intermediate updates. Blazor applies it before and after an event, but that doesn't help you here.

```
<button @onclick="@DoLogic">Load</button>
```

```
async Task DoLogic()
{
    edit = false;         // means loading == true
    StateHasChanged();    // to be sure, probably not needed
    await Task.Delay(1);  // allow time for the rendering

    // do the actual loading

    edit = true;          // means loading == false
}
```

The trick here is `await Task.Delay(1);` so your method is suspended for a bit and Blazor can update the DOM.

There is no reason for InvokeAsync here.

Comment: Thanks. Just saw your message. What I did was exactly that and yep, it worked. Thank you

Comment: thanks, this worked for me as well. was definitely the await Task.Delay(1); which did the trick, although unusual.